# Using Pagescroll with / before ID

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, cakephp

I am using pagescroll (Bootstrap) and it works fine when I use #scroll or #test as a link. But when I am using

```
<a href="/#experiences" class="page-scroll">Experiences</a>
```

It won´t. I guess it is because of the / , but I need it, so the menu goes back instead of just adding a #experiences to annother link like

```
www.test.de/othersite#experiences
```

That is my jQuery. Is this fixable in jQ?

```
$('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
    var $anchor = $(this);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: ($($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top - 50)
    }, 1250, 'easeInOutExpo');
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.replace()` to turn `"/#experiences"` to `"#experiences"`.

Example with your code:

```
$('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
    var $anchor = $(this);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: ($($anchor.attr('href').replace("/", "")).offset().top - 50)
    }, 1250, 'easeInOutExpo');
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

**Note:**

If what you are trying to do is have a url like this:
`www.test.de/othersite/#experiences`
Then this will not work because `\` is used to reference a path for the file in the HTTP request and so that will not be possible.

Comment: dang it. I tried this before with

var str = $(this);
        var $res = str.replace("/", "");

But it didn´t seem to work. Your replace works just fine. Thanks!